# HTML pattern for date. Only 1st of months

Tags: html, regex

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in pure HTML where using the date html object only allow the user to select the 1st of the month. Either a) by disabling the other options, or b) giving an error if they try to select a non first of the month.

Sadly I am not very great at regex, so I know the most likely solution to this would be to use the pattern field with the date to only allow for the 1st. Does anyone know if there is a regex for this for html, or another solution (not involving other libraries).

Comment: You could use [`<input type="month">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month)

Comment: @Moob not if I want it to work on some of the main browsers, such as firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you just need the user to select a month. Therefore, why not just use the html5 [`<input type="month">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month)?

```html
<input type="month" name="month" />
```

If it has to be a full date then you may have to use a JavaScript solution such as this. I don't think `input[type=date]` supports regex pattern.

```js
document.getElementById('date').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var date = new Date(this.value).getUTCDate();
  if(date>1){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = '';
    alert('Please pick the first day of the month.');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" />
```

Comment: Because it does not work in firefox. Else I agree, this would be the ideal solution I came to. I will give a try to the javascript solution later :)